# boost::multiprecision::export_bits lose sign when exporting cpp_int type to bits

Tags: c++, boost, bit

I export negative sign value to bits and import back, but when bits impotring sign has lost.

```
typedef multiprecision::int512_t balance_value;
vector<uint8_t> byteSet;
export_bits(static_cast<boost::multiprecision::int512_t>(balance), back_inserter(byteSet), 8);
```

When I try to import bits back to int512_t value's sign has lost.

```
balance_value balance;
import_bits(balance, byteSet.begin(), byteSet.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/import_export.html) states

> Exports the **absolute value** of val to `OutputIterator out`. The function will write `chunk_size` bits at a time to the `OutputIterator`, and if `msv_first` is true, will write the most-significant block first. Byte and bit order within each `chunk_size` block is always in the machines native format. Further, each block is stored in a `boost::uintmax_t` when it's assigned to `*out`.

Also pay attention to issues of endianness if you need a portable representation.

Comment: can you share an example ?

Comment: The samples are in the documentation.

Comment: So, you mean it's should be like that:
export_bits(static_cast<boost::multiprecision::checked_uint256_t>(amount), back_inserter(byteSet), 8, true);
import_bits(balance, bytesVector.begin(), bytesVector.end(), 8, true);

Comment: I don't know. Is your number unsigned? The point is, you seemed to complain the sign is lost, and that is by design. If you want to keep the sign, just serialize that separately.